# Running scrapy spider with Anaconda

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda, scrapy

Hello I am trying to complete the tutorial found at:

> https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html

I have completed all the steps up to "Our first Spider" without error however when I try to run the spider I get the following error message when I run "scrapy crawl quotes":

> File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py",
>   line 43, in load
>       raise KeyError("Spider not found: {}".format(spider_name)) KeyError: 'Spider not found: quotes'

So for some reason, the spider manager is not finding the spider. However, When I navigate directly to the spider directory I can find the spider without error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Scrapy command line option "crawl" requires a Scrapy project in order to find the specified spider, and start the crawl (see documentation [here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/commands.html?highlight=crawl#crawl), in which "Requires Project: *yes*" is listed).

Realistically, Scrapy would have no way of knowing the location of all Scrapy spiders on your system, picking one, and running it. For options that require a Project, you must be in the directory of the Scrapy project, which will have the file `scrapy.cfg` in it.

If you don't wish to use "crawl", you can use "runspider" instead, and specify the Python file containing the spider.